# Is it safe to longjmp through a try block?

Tags: c++, lua, try-catch, setjmp

I have the following lua_CFunction, written in C++:

```
int my_function(lua_State* L) {
    int x = 0;
    try {
        x = do_cpp_stuff_that_invokes_lua_API_as_well();
    } catch(const std::exception& ex) {
        lua_pushstring(ex.what().c_str());
        lua_error(L);
    }
    return x;
}
```

My question is the following: Is it OK to do a lua_error(L) or call any lua function that might longjmp:

- in the try block?
- in the catch block?

I take care of variables allocated on the stack simply by not allocating anything that would rely on a destructor (string, etc...). If I need to do that, than all the lua functions in that scope are wrapped in a pcall and if that pcall fails an exception is thrown to this function that I posted. *Simply I am concerned with try-catch blocks.*

Many thanks

Comment: If you compile Lua as a C++ library then it'll use exceptions instead of longjmp.

Comment: Great! I think I will compile it myself than as it saves me a lot of work. Thank you!

Comment: Anyway I am still curious if it is safe to longjmp through the try-catch block in my example. :)

Comment: no, exceptions use longjumps so why/how would/could it work?

Comment: I do not know whether exceptions use setjmp/longjmp in the background but even if they do, a setjmp/longjmp pair used by lua will not interact with that directly I guess, so this could work. In fact, T.C's answer below suggests quite an unrestrictive behaviour, it is only the non-trivially-destructible objects that I should take special care of then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relevant rule is (§18.10 [support.runtime]/p4):

> The function signature `longjmp(jmp_buf jbuf, int val)` has more
>   restricted behavior in this International Standard. A `setjmp/longjmp`
>   call pair has undefined behavior if replacing the `setjmp` and
>   `longjmp` by `catch` and `throw` would invoke any non-trivial
>   destructors for any automatic objects.

The C++ standard does not otherwise restrict the use of `setjmp` and `longjmp`.

Comment: It seems to me this would not be safe in most cases, as apparently what happens when you throw an object and catch by reference is that [the original object is destroyed at the throw site](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25724185/211160), so your reference is to a temporary...and this temporary's destructor won't be run if you longjmp in the catch body...?  (This seems to be what Yegor is saying.)

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing a long jump from a catch block, you are at least going to leak the memory used to store the exception object. The compiler generates the code freeing this memory on the control flow paths leading out of the catch block scope. If you do a long jump, none of these paths is taken.

[Sun Studio's documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19205-01/819-5267/bkahg/index.html) forbids mixing exceptions and longjmp explicitly:

> In particular, you must not longjmp into or out of a try-block or catch-block (directly or indirectly), or longjmp past the initialization or non-trivial destruction of auto variables or temporary variables.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! From today's perspective, this whole thing looks clearly like a terrible idea. :-) Fortunately in the question's comments it turned out that one may compile lua with having exceptions instead of longjmps and that solved the issue back then.

Comment: I answered a more generic question: is it generally safe to longjmp into/from try and catch blocks? The answer by T.C. implies that there is nothing wrong with this, which is actually not the case. I did not want the users to find that answer and start jumping back and forth without thinking. :)